# Does a lookup field on Account let us choose Person Account records as well?

Tags: lookup, person-accounts

I have an org with Person Accounts enabled. Having an object with a lookup relationship on Accounts, is it possible to add Person Accounts in this field?

Answer (score 2):

Its a same Account Object only the Type of Account is different. So you can select a person account in an Account lookup field.

PersonAccount is having 2 records 1 Account, 1 Contact, the fields exposed for that record depend how you are using it.  If you are using it in a Lookup(Account), you will see the Account fields.  If you are using it in a Lookup(Contact), you will see the Contact fields.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can also select a person account in an Account lookup field.

Answer (score 0):

Include the following in your lookup filter criteria: Is Person Account equals True.